# react native how to allow only one link to run inside webview for IOS?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a webview I want to allow to load pages only if they contains for example google.com as host , But I don't know how to implement that code ,
could you help me

```
jsCode() {
  //something here 
 }


      <WebView
          source={webapp}
          ref="WEBVIEW_REF"
          onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
          style={webView}
          startInLoadingState
          injectedJavascript={this.jsCode.bind(this)}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          domStorageEnabled={true}
          decelerationRate="fast"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `onNavigationStateChange` prop with a function that checks the domain of the url.  If the url is not allowed, render an error instead.

```js
_onNavigationStateChange(webViewState){
  console.log(webViewState.url)
}
```

webviewState object prototype:

```js
{
  canGoBack: bool,
  canGoForward: bool,
  loading: bool,
  target: number,
  title: string,
  url: string,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional rendering of react-native.

Something similar to this:

```
render(){
   return yourCondition ? <WebView/> : <AnotherView/>
}
```

Just check the host name in yourCondition.

Answer (score 0):

You should verify first what host you are getting. After it, you return depending of the result.

Something like this:

```
render(){
    const allowHost = "google.com";

    const verifyHost = (url, allowHost) => {
        let host;

        // Do logic to verify if the url host is equal to the allowHost...
        ...

        return host === allowHost;
    }

    return verifyHost(url, allowHost) ? <WebView/> : <View>This URL is not allowed.</View>
}
```